# how can i test x509 with kotlin and junit

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, junit, x509certificate, x509

I have a spring boot application developed with kotlin that run http on port 8081 and https on port 8082.
I developed an x509 authentication mechanism and i like to develop an integration test with junit and spring boot to test the call to https entry with client x509certificate.

How can i develop the spring boot test running on two ports one for http and another for https? and how can i pass the client certificate with unirest call?

i tried to add a jakarta.servlet.request.X509Certificate header in unirest get but that does not work.

thank's!